# Understanding the proof a metrizable connected space has uncountable elements if $|X|\geqslant 2$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-writing, proof-explanation

> **Exercise**: Using the fact $d$ is a metric hence continuous. Prove that if a metrizable space $(X,\tau)$ is connected and $X$ has at least 2 points, then $X$ has uncountable number of points.

I found the following answer on Mathstackexchange by Mariano Suárez-Álvarez

> Let your points be $a$ and $b$.
>
> Let $\lambda\in(0,1)$ Suppose there is no point $x$ in your space such that $d(a,x)=\lambda d(a,b)$. Then the sets $\{z:d(a,z)<\lambda d(a,b)\}$ and $\{z:d(a,z)>\lambda d(a,b)\}$ are two non-empty open sets which partition the space.
>
> Since we are assuming connectedness, this is impossible.
>
> Therefore, the image of the function $d(a,\mathord\cdot):X\to\mathbb R$ contains the interval $(0,d(a,b))$, and this can only happen if $X$ is uncountable.

**Questions:**

**1)** Why does the author uses $\lambda$? If instead the author used $d(a,b)$ and all other points were diferent from $b$ the distance would still be different, allowing the disjoint partition of the space.

**2)**
I know the metric is continuous function into $\mathbb{R}$. How does the author deduces that the image contains $(0,d(a,b))$? How does that relate to the previous argument of the partition?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand your questions.  The writer's $\lambda$ argument appears to make sense, no?  It's possible, of course, that you have an alternate argument, though I don't understand what you wrote.  That wouldn't invalidate the given argument though.  And I can't follow question $2$ at all.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for reading! On point 1) I am writing about how would the proof work if $\lambda$ was absent. On point 2) there was a flaw I forgot to write the interval. I do not understand how the author deduces the image of $d(a,.):X\to\mathbb{R}$ contains the open interval (0,d(a,b)) on the real line. Hope I was a  clearer.

Comment: Hint: the first paragraph proves that for any $\rho \in (0, d(a, b))$, there is a point $x$ such that $d(a, x) = \rho$ (by taking $\lambda = \rho/d(a, b)$).

Comment: The author takes $r\in(0,d(a,b))$ and shows that there exists $x$ such that $d(a,x)=r$.

Comment: What do you mean in question 1? What would the partition you re describing be?

Comment: The point of the lambda argument is precisely to show that every point in the interval $[0,d(a,b)]$ is in the image of $d$.

Comment: @RobArthan I understood your hint. But I cannot see why that would imply that I would have uncountable points in $X$ since it starts with a finite number of points. How would the increase in points impede the contradiction of $(X,\tau)$ being connected?

Comment: @lulu I know that insofar but I do not understand the mechanism. Could you explain it?

Comment: Any set which surjects onto an uncountable set must itself be uncountable.

Comment: @lulu       I know that as well. The problem is that I am not understanding how the author is proving that.

Comment: @metamorphy How does the author proves there is an $x$ such that $d(a,x)=r$?

Comment: The argument appears to be entirely straight forward.  If $0<r<d(a,b)$ then let $\lambda = \frac r{d(a,b)}$.  We note that $0<\lambda <1$ so we can apply the writer's argument to deduce the existence of $x$ such that $d(a,x)=\lambda \times d(a,b)=r$.

Comment: @lulu Why not an official answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your confusion arises because the proof you quote only uses continuity of the metric in a rather artificial way. Here are two proofs, the first doesn't really use the continuity and the second does. In both proofs, we assume $X$ is connected and metrizable and has at least two points, say $a \neq b$.

1. Let $\lambda \in (0, 1)$. I claim that $d(a, z) = \lambda d(a, b)$ for some $z = z(\lambda)\in X$, for, if not, the sets $\{z:d(a,z)<\lambda d(a,b)\}$ and $\{z:d(a,z)>\lambda d(a,b)\}$ are non-empty, open, disjoint and partition $X$, leading to a contradiction because $X$ is connected. Since there are uncountably many $\lambda \in (0, 1)$, and $d(a, b) \neq 0$ there must be uncountable many $z(\lambda) \in X$. (This is the proof you quote adapted to remove the artificial appeal to continuity of the metric.).
2. Consider the function $f : X \to \Bbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = d(a, x)$. $f$ is continuous and hence the image $I = f[X]$ is a connected subspace of $\Bbb{R}$, because $X$ is connected and the continuous image of a connected set is connected. A non-empty connected subset of $\Bbb{R}$ is either a single point or an interval. As $f(a) = d(a, a) = 0$ and $f(b) = d(a, b) \neq 0$, $I$ is an interval and so contains uncountably many points. Thus the uncountable set $I$ is an image of $X$ and hence $X$ must be uncountable.

Comment: I think that (2) is essentially just (1), because you need to prove that connected sets are intervals. The proof in (1) includes the fact that any interval which contains two points contains the entire interval. This is the proof I would use to check the stated property. Also, (1) absolutely needs continuity of the metric, otherwise there is no reason to believe that the inverse image of these open sets are open.

Comment: I've just written a comment on your answer disagreeing with the comment that you were writing at the same time $\ddot{\smile}$. That those two inverse images are open follows from first principles from the definition of open sets wrt a metric. I am very happy to agree to differ: the important thing is that the OP understands what's going on. Cheers!

Comment: Ok, sure, I grant my second point :) But I think that we are just playing word games, since the definition of open set encodes continuity of the metric. And of course I agree this sort of disagreement is just for fun.

Comment: I am not sure it is entirely about word games. The statement that the metric is continuous presupposes an understanding of the product topology, whereas the problem and the proof here don't require that.

Comment: I really only meant the function $x \mapsto d(a, x)$, which is all either of us use. anyway, I'll let you spend your time on something more productive!

Answer (score 2):

If it helps, the idea of the argument is two parts.

1) If $f: X \to Y$ is a continuous map and $X$ is connected, then so is $f(X)$. It suffices to assume $f$ is surjective (otherwise, replace $Y$ with $f(X)$ with the subspace topology).

If $f$ is surjective, then given any pair of open sets $U_1, U_2 \subset Y$ with $U_1 \cap U_2 = \varnothing$ and $U_1 \cup U_2 = Y$, we may take the inverse image to obtain $f^{-1}(U_1)$ and $f^{-1}(U_2)$. These are nonempty if and only of the corresponding $U_i$ is nonempty; furthermore their intersection is trivial and union is all of $X$ (this does not use surjectivity). Therefore, if $U_1 \cup U_2 = Y$ is a disconnection of $Y$ (that is, neither $U_i$ is the empty set), then the same is true of $f^{-1}(U_1) \cup f^{-1}(U_2) = X$, and so if $Y$ is disconnected so is $X$, as desired.

2) If $I$ is a connected subset of the real line, if $a, b \in I$, then $[a, b] \subset I$. For if not, choose $x \in (a,b)$ not in $I$, and write $I = \left((-\infty, x) \cap I\right) \cup \left(x, \infty) \cap I\right)$ to obtain a disconnection of $I$.

Now consider the conditions map $X \to [0,\infty)$ given by $x \mapsto d(a,x)$. This has image containing both $d(a,a) = 0$ and $d(a,b) \neq 0$. So therefore the image must contain all of $[0, d(a,b)]$ and hence must be uncountable; so the domain is as well.

Mariano rolled these two points into one proof: he took the open sets $U_1$ and $U_2$ in the first step to be $(0, x)$ and $(x, d(a,b))$ if $x$ is not in the image.

Comment: I find it hard to fit your explanation to the quoted proof, which contains no instance of the assertion that the continuous image of a connected set is connected (your part (1)).

Comment: @RobArthan not explicitly, but the entire point of the proof is to show that a continuous map $f: X \to \Bbb R$ from connected $X$ which contains $a$ and $b$ indeed contains $[a, b]$. To do that you are implicitly showing that $f(X)$ is path-connected (hence connected). Of course, Mariano's proof does both in one step. This is what my last line was supposed to indicate.

Comment: I don't agree. See my answer: my proof (1) is the real essence of Mariano's proof and does not involve what you claim is the "entire point of the proof". Personally, I prefer my proof (2), which is the same as the proof you give, but I can see why the OP might be confused given a (correct, but over-complicated) mixture of the two proofs.

Comment: @RobArthan I disagree that there is any difference in the idea in the two proofs, and we will have to leave it at that.